# Firebase - whats the best way to login with 2 different user types e.g. a user and a company

Tags: firebase

Whats the best way to login with 2 different user types e.g. a user and a company

A user sees one type of view journey
And a company sees another type of view journey.

2 different user flows.

When a user or company register I ideally would like to store type as a field with it. So on login I can check the type.

Is there a way to do this or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Users themselves can't have additional data directly stored on them. Instead create a root collection, eg `users` with additional data.

```
"users"{
  "angularm@example.com":{
    "type":"business"
  }
}
```

and then just reference that collection using the logged in user's email (or structure it with IDs, etc).

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same thing but with profiles.

I have a profiles table json that tells me the users type. I'm guessing thats the same thing your refering to but another way?

Comment: Sure, the name of the collection doesn't matter. If you have a way that if given an ID you can get the info you need about the user, than you should have what you need to do the switching you want.

Comment: Dylan is spot on. The UID from firebase users is a unique key that you can create a "users" collection or in your case a "profiles" collection. My .02 is make a users collection and make profile info a child of each user. That way you can do stuff with Security rules faster and it make semantic sense. Consider: `if(user.isBanned){...}` makes more sense than: `if(profile.isBanned)`